# Wordpress media file upload 403 forbidden

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, file-upload

I'm trying to upload files in wordpress but I'm getting http error 403 forbidden for certain files. The images are the same resolution, hardly differs anything in size and the mime types are the same.

I am using apache2 with php 7.0, however this problem seems to persist over multiple servers with different php versions.

php.ini settings

```
upload_max_filesize = 512M
post_max_size = 128M
```

I've even tried adding it to the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

        RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

        # add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
        RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]
        RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
        RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
        RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

php_value upload_max_filesize 512M
php_value post_max_size 512M
php_value memory_limit 512M
```

I am not using mod_security so the upload limit does not apply here.
this is the output from apachectl -M:

```
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_prefork_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 php7_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

It seems to be due to a firewall setting, sysadmin tried deactivating "Protocol Violations" and it started working normally.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same issue. I tried to upload an image directly in the editor view of my post. I guess that I had it open for too long (over 24 hours) and some token or something expired. After a reload of the editor, it worked just fine again

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the folder permissions of the upload folders. Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Answer (score 0):

Add only below code to yours.htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

hope it will work for you